# How to get latest files based on lastmodified using unix

Tags: unit-testing, unix

currently I'm using below command to get latest 4 files. 
But this command also fetches directories...but i want to exclude directory. How to do?

ls -tr /home/user | tail -4

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the files to show you can issue:

```
for i in `ls -tr /home/user`; do if test -f $i; then echo $i; fi done | tail -4
```

-f flag on test checks if argument is a file
-d flag on test checks if argument is a directory

Comment: Thanks for your input.

Comment: ls -tr `find . -name "*.ZZAX" -type f ` | tail -4